# To stop a user to visit a page directly from URL but should also allow specific URL in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, url, model-view-controller, web-config

We are developing a MVC application and we want to stop any adhoc user to visit any particular url directly and redirect to home page we are able to achieve this by the below code.

```
string url = Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority)+"/Area/Controller/Home";

if ((Request.UrlReferrer == null) && (Request.Url.ToString().ToLower() != url.ToLower()))
{                
    Response.Redirect(url);
}
```

But at the same time we want to allow some URL which are basically sent to Users for validation to continue to that page.

I have one approach which is:

1. Put the exempted URL in web.config file.
2. Put if else condition for each URL in main controller and then redirect the user to the particular page.

Let me know if there is any other good method to do this.

Comment: **Adhoc** user do you mean **Anonymous** user ? If you want to prevent anonymous user from accessing any action you can simply use **Authorize** attribute. Doesn't that work for you ?

Comment: No, for example url for Home page is Controller\Home\ from there user is going to \Home\SecondPage. So now if the user is directly hitting \Home\SecondPage he should be redirected to Controller\Home\